# Concatenate values from another workbook with parameters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'd like to modify this code fragment to concatenate values from 2 cells from another workbook.

```
OpenedWb.Worksheets(DestinationSheet).Range("E23:I23").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=[" & mainFilename & "]" & mainSheet & "!" & SelectedData.EntireRow.Cells(1, "U").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

I've tried several method including this:

```
OpenedWb.Worksheets(DestinationSheet).Range("E23:I23").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE([" & mainFilename & "]" & mainSheet & "!" & SelectedData.EntireRow.Cells(1, "U").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ";" & "[" & mainFilename & "]" & mainSheet & "!" & SelectedData.EntireRow.Cells(1, "V").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"
```

I can't figure it out how to add the concatenate formula. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using , instead of ; solved this problem. In this way, the formula converts VBA's comma to semicolon.

```
OpenedWb.Worksheets(DestinationSheet).Range("E23") = "=Concatenate([" & mainFilename & "]" & mainSheet & "!" & SelectedData.EntireRow.Cells(1, "U").Address & ",A11" & ")"
```